# Check a checkbox in an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Good afternoon,

I am trying to tick a checkbox in my html page using a script.

Unfortunately, I get the following error message :

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'checked' of undefined or null reference
>   File: ajax3, Line: 37, Column: 5

Do you have an idea what went wrong in my code?

Thanks a lot and have a great Sunday.

Laurent

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Demo for Ajax Auto Refresh</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_day.css" />
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.news);
                sayHello();
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 1 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,1000);
</script>
<script>
function sayHello(){
    //console.log("Coucou");
    check();
}
function check() {
document.getElementById("chk1").checked = true;
}

function uncheck() {
document.getElementById("chk1").checked = false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">

</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1"> Living room<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2"> Entrance<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3"> Kitchen<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The checkboxes don't have `id` attributes.

Comment: use `id="chk1"` instead of `value="chk1"`

Comment: great thanks a lot. I have corrected my code above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by nmnsud and gcampbell, I have replaced value="chk1" by id="chk1". The correct bit of code is now the following :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1"> Living room<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2"> Entrance<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3"> Kitchen<br>
```

Thanks a lot for your contribution. Best wishes,
Laurent